# in my case, "nice" command is not really helpful in linux

Tags: linux, kernel

the following is my a.out code.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
main(){
int i;
  while(1){
    i++;
  }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I execute a.out program in linux with command below.

## nice -n 19 ./a.out

but "top" command always shows more than 95% CPU using percent, like below.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                   
18855 root      39  19    4196    632    552 R  99.9  0.0   0:08.34 a.out
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I really really like to make my a.out program to use lower than 30% cpu using percent,,, but It's really difficult to me...

ps. I used "ionice" command, but it's not help neither...

Comment: AFAIK, nice doesn't limit the CPU usage of a process, it only adjusts its priority. Meaning that if no other process is needing the CPU, there's no reason for this process to use less than the maximum CPU power it can.

Comment: Did you try running the same without nice or different priority level(niceness) ? As also already stated if there is not other process needing the CPU, then this shall be utilizing the CPU.

Comment: yeah... I did... you're right... nice command does not work in top command... if nice value is 19, a.out use 99% cpu, and if nice value is -20, a.out use 99% either!!!

Comment: BTW....................do you know how can i control CPU usage % lower than 30% by linux command....?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that in the first place ? Why limit your process CPU usage ? When nice'd, this process will leave it to other processes when needed.